# How to start webcam video recording (in viddler) using javascript?

Tags: video, webcam, video-recording

We are using viddler for recording videos for a contest. But we need the "RECORD" button to be different from the button in the recorder. It is posible to start recording using javascript so we can use a different button in the webpage?

Thanks to all

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can design your own button and point it to do what the old one does with javascript. I could help more if you post your code.